# How to configure update operation in Command-line interface for Force.com

Tags: data-loader, force-cli

What should I give in configuration like:

```
<entry key="sfdc.loadBatchSize" value="500"/>
<entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Opportunity"/>
<entry key="sfdc.Id" value="id"/>
<entry key="process.operation" value="update"/>
```

Using like this giving me error:

> Id not specified in update call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify `key="sfdc.Id"`.
If you have extracted `*.csv` with opportunities and have configured mapping `*.sdl` update operation should work.

opportunityUpdateMap.sdl:

```
NAME=Name
ID=Id
```

extract.csv:

```
"ID","NAME"
"00636000006FRAZAA4","Boston"
"00636000006FRAtAAO","Washington"
```

process-conf.xml:

```
<property name="name" value="csvUpdateOpp"/>
<property name="configOverrideMap">
    <map>
        //...
        <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Opportunity"/>
        <entry key="process.operation" value="update"/>
        <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="<..>\opportunityUpdateMap.sdl"/>
        <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="<..>\extract.csv" /> 
    </map>
</property>
```

You could refer to your own samples directory and check extract, update etc. operations

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\salesforce.com\Data Loader\samples\conf
```